# close windows application with sql query

Tags: sql, windows

I want to write a job in sql server that stop and run a specific windows form application.
is it possible to close a windows application with sql query or not?
if not, how can I do that? can I use vb.net?
I did use this code (EXEC MASTER.. xp_cmdshell     'taskkill /im filename.exe')
but get access denied error
thanks

Comment: without knowing the specifics it's very difficult to give advice. You coud use xp_cmdshell but you'd probably be better off by driving your process from powershell.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution

I Can use SqlServer to close and open .exe files with (EXEC master.dbo.xp_cmdshell 'taskkill /F /IM filename.exe')
but before running we most use
  EXEC sp_configure 'xp_cmdshell', 1
    RECONFIGURE
   GO
to enable xp_cmdshell
but still we get access is denied error becouse:

when SQL server tries to access anything outside of the SQL instance(xp_cmdshell, files/folders/, network shares, anything outside of it's own databases)

it uses it's own startup account to do it. it's THAT account that has to have permissions to browse to network services...most likely, right now it does not.

Go to Control Panel/Administrative Tools>>Services>> find the instance of SQL server you are referencing:
the account shown here most likely needs to be changes from local account to an admin account that would have permissions to login to your domain, and browse to shares.